# setValue and sendKeys throw error to set a text in EditText with Appium and Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, appium, sendkeys, setvalue

What I try to do in order to test my `LoginActivity` is to set a text in the email `Edittext` using Appium and Android Studio.

My 1st version of the test included a `WebDriver` and a `Webelement` for the `EditText`, so i used `sendKeys()` to set the text.

This is the code:

```
WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    String apkpath = "C:\\Users\\0013498\\Desktop\\qa-XXX-2-2-4-2.apk";
    File app = new File(apkpath);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.XXX.XXX");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.XXX.XXX.SplashScreenActivity");
    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}


@Test
public void appiumExampleTest() throws Exception {
String path="//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,\"email\")]";
    click(path);
    elementSendText(path, "@");
}
public void click(String element) {
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
    webElement.click();
    System.out.println("Click element: "+element+" index = "+0);

}


public void elementSendText(String element,  String text) {
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
    webElement.sendKeys(text);

}
```

this is the screenshot from UI Automator Viewer for the `LoginActivity` where the email `EditText` is :

[image]

BUT `sendKeys()` throws the following error:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.`

So, after some digging, i changed my code to start using `AndroidDriver` and `AndroidElement` like this:

```
AndroidDriver driver;
@Before
public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    String apkpath = "C:\\Users\\0013498\\Desktop\\qa-XXX-2-2-4-2.apk";
    File app = new File(apkpath);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.XXX.XXX");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.XXX.XXX.SplashScreenActivity");       
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"),capabilities);//<----
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
@Test
public void appiumExampleTest() throws Exception {
AndroidElement emailET= (AndroidElement)driver.findElementById("com.XXX.XXX:id/email");//<----
    emailET.click();//<----
    emailET.setValue("@");
}
```

and now, setValue() throws the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented.
```

And honestly, I don't know how to move forward, i'm so stuck here. This can't be that difficult, what am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

as requested in one of the answers, this is the full error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 77 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'PC0C283Q', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_76-release'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Capabilities [{app=C:\Users\0013498\Desktop\qa-XXX-2-2-4-2.apk, appPackage=com.XXX.XXX, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=WKS8DAV8GEYTQGB6, platform=LINUX, appActivity=com.XXX.XXX.SplashScreenActivity, desired={app=C:\Users\0013498\Desktop\qa-interview-2-2-4-2.apk, appPackage=com.XXX.XXX, appActivity=com.XXX.XXX.SplashScreenActivity, platformName=Android, deviceName=Emulator}, platformVersion=6.0, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=Android, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: 3f61a37c-0f35-487c-be76-97154a8b6e04

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:45)
at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement.execute(AndroidElement.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:98)
at com.cheerle.mongentesting01.test02.elementSendText(test02.java:150)
at com.cheerle.mongentesting01.test02.appiumExampleTest(test02.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**EDIT:**

maybe build.gradle has sth to do with the issue?

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cheerle.mongentesting01"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/java-client-5.0.0-BETA3.jar')
    compile files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar')
}
```

in the project:

[image]

Also, Run Configuration settings I have my test02 like this:

[image]

This is Appium server screen & configs:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

Try **emailET.sendKeys("@")**; with AndroidDriver code which you posted.

Comment: it throws the error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

Comment: i copied the error in the question, last edit, thanks

Comment: what you added is execution logs. could you upload Appium Server logs.  One more question, the login screen which you posted , does it native or  webview of your app?

Comment: Screenshot is fine. Run Appium server, execute your code and capture the Appium logs and upload. 1st screenshot after  "This is Appium server screen & configs:"  title which you post

Comment: as Appium Server Logs were large, i pasted it in here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y3OjU9tycwGvjppM8atbP5E5_ubm11oXYc8Nuv3A648/edit?usp=sharing You should be able to access. Thanks a lot.

Comment: well, i thought that the click() was working, but it is not. The problem must be in the findElement... sth must be wrong in the way i get the webelement

Comment: Yes.  Appium logs > info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,"email")] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "}

Comment: //*[contains(@resource-id,"email")] . Try this in xpath

Comment: same error, also saying :"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. ". i triedL driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id,'email')]")); double quotes gave error

Comment: Try it out with ID.  driver.findElementById("com.XXX.XXX:id/email")

Comment: i tried WebElement passwordET = driver.findElementById("com.mobgen.interview.mobgeninterviewtest:id/password"); same error: "Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "

Comment: I have also tried: WebElement passwordET = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mobgen.interview.mobgeninterviewtest:id/password")); same error again: "Could not find an element using supplied strategy. " T.T

Comment: App the current view is Native or Webview ?

Comment: how can i know that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the EditText element. Just add the following code instead of you setValue or sendKeys code.

```
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("textToBeTyped");
```

Comment: when i use driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("@"); in my 1st version of the code (using WebDriver and WebElement) the method getKeyboard() cannot be resolved.